# Import extrenal text into forest

Tags: symbols, verbatim, forest, characters

I want to import a text file into forest and have it as it is without using latex symbols. I found `verbatiminput` as possible choice but it doesn't work as I expect and outputs some strange chars:

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 [\verbatiminput{input.txt}]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

input.txt contains the following text:

```
I need to have as many ascii chars as possible without any conversion:
33 ! (exclamation mark)
34 " (Quotation mark) 
35 # (Number sign)
36 $ (Dollar sign)
37 % (Percent sign)
38 & (Ampersand)
39 ' (Apostrophe) 
40 ( (round brackets or parentheses)
41 ) (round brackets or parentheses)
42 * (Asterisk) 
43 + (Plus sign)
44 , (Comma)
45 - (Hyphen)
46 . (Full stop , dot)
47 / (Slash)
58 : (Colon)
59 ; (Semicolon)
60 < (Less-than sign )
61 = (Equals sign)
62 > (Greater-than sign ; Inequality)  
63 ? (Question mark)
64 @ (At sign)_
91 [ (square brackets or box brackets)
92 \ (Backslash)
93 ] (square brackets or box brackets)
94 ^ (Caret or circumflex accent)
95 _ (underscore , understrike , underbar or low line)
96 ` (Grave accent) 
123 { (curly brackets or braces)
124 | (vertical-bar, vbar, vertical line or vertical slash)
125 } (curly brackets or braces)
126 ~ (Tilde ; swung dash)
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please hint at what output you’re expecting with `forest`?

Comment: What I want to create is a tree that reads its input from external text files. My question refers to one of the nodes...

Comment: A node in the forest that’s 30 lines long and as wide as the long text in the last line thereof?

Comment: for this question yes. you may take a look at the answer and my comments.

Comment: You need gigantic pages to accommodate such things in a `forest`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664982/import-multi-external-files-into-forest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the contents of the `\verbatiminput` into a box and then use this box in your obscure environment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newbox\verbbox

\begin{document}

\setbox\verbbox=\vbox{\verbatiminput{input.txt}}
\begin{forest}
 [\box\verbbox]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine except for one thing: the first line of my text gets truncated and I receive this warning: Overfull \hbox (22.4968pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--7 . Is there a way to force text to stay fully inside the box?

Comment: Also, i have another problem. I need to import more than one input. How can I extend this solution to do so? Well, I asked too many questions, so I write another question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664982/import-multi-external-files-into-forest