# import multi external files into forest

Tags: symbols, verbatim, forest, characters

I want to import many input text files inside a forest. Here is an example to illustrate my idea:

input1.txt

```
This line is a long sentence that may need more space to fit inside a single line.
This is a new line that I expect to go right after the above line.
And here is a line with some special characters: @#_'"$[]{}()/\
```

input2.txt

```
here goes input2.txt content
```

Here is my starting code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newbox\verbbox

\begin{document}

\setbox\verbbox=\vbox{\verbatiminput{input1.txt}}


\begin{forest}
 [root,draw
[\box\verbbox,draw]
     [here goes input2.txt content,draw]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The output

[image]

There are two problems with the code above:

1. It works only with one single input
2. input text doesn't fit properly inside the box

Here is what I expect as output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest writing a style to input the file.  It also seems that package `verbatimbox` is preferable here, as it adapts the width of the box to the width of the file content.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\forestset{
  verbatim input/.style={
    content={\verbfilebox{#1}\theverbbox},
    fill=yellow,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree=draw,
 [root
   [,verbatim input=input1.txt]
   [branch
     [,verbatim input=input2.txt]
     [,verbatim input=input3.txt]
   ]
 ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer! let me check it and then I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can read more boxes before their usage in the environment. Each box has its inividual number. And you can use `\top` instead `\vbox` if you want to align to the first line.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\def\infile#1#2{\setbox\numexpr1000+#1=\vtop{\verbatiminput{#2}}}
\def\putfile#1{\box\numexpr1000+#1\relax}

\begin{document}

\infile 1 {input.txt}
\infile 2 {input2.txt}

\begin{forest}
 [root,draw
[\putfile1,draw]
     [\putfile2,draw]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately, it doesn't adapt to the width.